# Solving a variant of the Poisson Boltzmann equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, poissons-equation

The following is an equation I've derived in my personal research:

> $$ \frac{d^2V}{dx^2}=e^{\alpha x} \sinh(V) $$

I'm looking to solve it explicitly for V(x).
It's a variant of the Poisson-Boltzmann equation, which has the form $ \frac{d^2V}{dx^2}= \sinh(V) $, and can be solved by multiplying both sides by $ \frac{dV}{dx} $ and integrating, rearranging and integrating again.

I've tried several methods, changes of variables, separation of variables, integration by parts, etc. The best I can do is a change of variable, $ y=e^{\alpha x} $ which yields:

> $$ \alpha^2(V_{yy} \cdot y +V_v) = \sinh(V)  $$

OR equivalently...

> $$ \alpha^2 \frac{d}{dy}(yV_y) = \sinh(V)  $$

But again I can't get any further than this.

> A) Can it be solved explicitly? If so, how?
>
> B) Is there a name for this equation so I can find other information on it and it's properties?

I have a suspicion that some change to a complex variable and contour integrals might be involved in solving this but I can't be sure since I took a took an introductory complex analysis class almost 10 years ago.

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method to solve this equation

Comment: Is there some reason it can't be solved analytically?

Comment: Of course it can be solved analytically, but not nowadays. You will have to wait until somebody defines a new special function especially convenient and that this special function be standardized. This is a very usual situation, for example $y''=e^{ax}y(x)$ was not solvable on closed form until the Bessel functions were defined and standardized. Now, this ODE is analytically solvable in terms of Bessel functions.